# Create dynamic html & display json values in it

Tags: jquery, html, css, json, ajax

I have call ajax api call, i get response in json format. I want to display each values on screen with html elements. I've achieve this but it wont create dynamic design as i needed. Also i wan to show an message("No data available") if there is no data in response. Here is my working HTML & JSON sample.
Need to display as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="portlet light bg-inverse tripcontainer">
        <div id="container">
            <div class="col-md-4 driver">
                <div>
                    <label class="header">Driver Details</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <span class="dname"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Vehicle No:</label>
                    <span class="dvehicle"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Mobile No:</label>
                    <span class="dmob"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <span class="demail"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Start Location:</label>
                    <span class="dstart"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Lat:</label>
                    <span class="dlat"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Long:</label>
                    <span class="dlong"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>End Location:</label>
                    <span class="dend"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Lat:</label>
                    <span class="dselat"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Long:</label>
                    <span class="dselong"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Booked Seats:</label>
                    <span class="dseat"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Start Time:</label>
                    <span class="dstarttime"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Route ID:</label>
                    <span class="droute"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Distance:</label>
                    <span class="ddistance"></span>KM</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 passanger">
                <div>
                    <label class="header">Passanger Details</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <span class="pname"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Mobile No:</label>
                    <span class="pmob"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <span class="pemail"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Start Location:</label>
                    <span class="pstart"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Lat:</label>
                    <span class="pslat"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Long:</label>
                    <span class="pelong"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>End Location:</label>
                    <span class="pend"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Lat:</label>
                    <span class="pelat"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Long:</label>
                    <span class="pelong"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Booked Seats:</label>
                    <span class="pseat"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Start Time:</label>
                    <span class="pstarttie"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>End Time:</label>
                    <span class="pendtime"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Distance:</label>
                    <span class="pdistance"></span>KM</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Can you please paste expected result?

Comment: I have update my question, pls have a look

Comment: I don't understand why you create first an empty "container" and then fill it with your ajax call. Could not you create and populate everything together in ajax call? Maybe it's simpler, I think.

Comment: @ReSendano
I can't, could you pls help in this?

Comment: Where is the JSON Sample @Jon

Comment: @Jon Please post your ajax code and specify where you are having the actual problem.

Comment: Json format in fiddle below my js code
http://jsfiddle.net/eLpcybk2/22/

Comment: @CodeThing
Pls check above fiddle with json fomat

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well you want to fill each information
So to parse with javascript you can do :

```
var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(ajaxesponse);
if(parsedResponse.length = 0){
   console.log('No data');
}else{
   var keys = Object.keys(parsedResponse[0]);
   //parsedResponse[0] for driver data
   for(var i = 0; i < keys.length ; i++){
      //The best thing to do is to change your class name and name it the same way as your keys in the response object
      $("."+keys[i]).html(parsedResponse[0][keys[i]]);
   }
}
```

And your html :
instead of

```
<div>
   <label>Email:</label>
   <span class="demail"></span>
</div>
```

You have something like that

```
<div>
   <label>Email:</label>
   <span class="email"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Pls check updated fiddle with json format
http://jsfiddle.net/eLpcybk2/22/

Comment: I dint undersatand

Answer (score 0):

To make this dynamic you can follow these steps

**1. Assign values for driver like this**

```
$('.dname').html(driver_data[0].employeename);
```

**2. Assign values for passenger like this**

```
$('.pname').html(driver_data[0].passenger_data[0].employeename);
```

**3. Iterate through your result (This should be first)**

```
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
// your assignments here
}
```

Here i have parsed and appended values in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrxbu2vo/6/)**

This is how it looks like after appending

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**Note :**

1. I have appended few fields for driver and passenger you should iterate through it and make it fit for your wish.
2. You don't need to create static HTML, instead you can do this from jquery itself. So that you can have less code.

**Update :**

As the OP wants how to iterate through the result and fix the data in it.

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrxbu2vo/17/) which iterates dynamically

This is how it looks like

[![Output][4]][4]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ba349e82f000054009685b0", function(data, status) {
        var output = '';
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var driverHtml = '<div class="col-md-4 driver"><div><label class="header">Driver Details</label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="dname">' + data[i].employeename + '</span></div>';
            var passengerHtml = '<div class="col-md-8 passenger"><div><label class="header">Passenger Details</label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="pname">' + data[i].passenger_data[0].employeename + '</span></div><hr>';
            output += driverHtml + passengerHtml;
        }
        $('#container').html(output);
    });
});
```

**Note for update :**

I have used [Mocky](https://www.mocky.io/) for the Data to simulate the [real time output like this](http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ba349e82f000054009685b0)

I have created HTML also dynamically and filled only few fields. You can fill the remaining fields too.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I dint get you, pls explain

Comment: 3. Iterate through your result, how it will give the structure which i needed

Comment: Ok wait i will iterate through result and parse it for you

Comment: There are many fields in your html i will do it only for 3 fields for driver and passenger. You can just fill in other details by your own is that ok for you ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Here is the fiddle with dynamic iteration http://jsfiddle.net/qrxbu2vo/19/

Comment: @Jon I have just provided answer for appending datas dynamically . I looked on your latest fiddle that's another issue you can ask that in another question. I will help you in that in separate thread.

Comment: @Sultan   Its a same question, i update as you suggest but it won't work, just check my fiddle & let me know is there anything missing or not??

Comment: @Sultan, did you check my fiddle

Comment: It has numerous errors `url: "API URL" + obj + '/' + objs,` getting data is the first error

Comment: @Sultan I have provided json format, which i get it from API call, after that i manipulated with api response as you suggested.

Comment: If you run the jsfiddle and see the console its in error. Need to fix those step by step

Comment: @Sultan, I have tried with your code, get API response also, but it won't create html structure & display values in it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways in order to populate JSON data in HTML i.e. Ajax, getJSON, Fetch, JavaScript (pure), XMLHttpRequest.

Here is an example using fetch() method below. You can modify it according to your own needs:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody id="my-list">
            <tr>
                <th>Field 01</th>
                <th>Field 02</th>
                <th>Field 03</th>
                <th>Field 04</th>
                <th>Field 05</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<script>

$(function () {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
    fetch(url, { /* other parameters */ })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => { // Your code for handling the data you get from the API
            renderData(data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) { // This is where you run code if the server returns any errors
            console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ', error.message);
        });
});


function renderList(data) {
    var list = "";
    $.each(data, function (index) {
        href = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?id=" + data[index].Id;
        list += "<tr>";
        list += "<td>" + data[index].Field01 + "</td>";
        list += "<td>" + data[index].Field02 + "</td>";
        list += "<td>" + data[index].Field03 + "</td>";
        list += "<td>" + data[index].Field04 + "</td>";
        list += "<td>" + data[index].Field05 + "</td>";
        list += "</tr>";
    })
    $("#my-list").append(list);
}

</script>
```

Hope this helps...