# Can not create dynamic html using ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

I have call ajax api call & i get response in json format. I want to create dynamic HTML & display each values in HTML elements. I tried i get response from API but it wont create HTML. Can anyone help me to sort it out. Also want to show Message if response having empty json (No data available)
My expected out put is if 3 passengers then show all 3 columns with details if 2 then it will shows only 2 columns with details, if 1 then it will shows only 1 columns with details as screenshot.
If no passenger it'll show a message "No passenger available"

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Json success function shows 
[Image][2]

**I have apply solution which provided**

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[Fiddle][4]

My current code

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

            $.get("http://10.26.32.4:8765/api/rating-service/rate/trip/getdetails/30/COMPLETED", function(data, status) {
                var output = '';
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var driverHtml = '<div class="col-md-4 driver"><div><label class="header">Driver Details</label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="dname">' + data[i].employeename + '</span></div>';
                    var passengerHtml = '<div class="col-md-8 passenger"><div><label class="header">Passenger Details</label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="pname">' + data[i].passenger_data[0].employeename + '</span></div><hr>';
                    output += driverHtml + passengerHtml;
                }
                $('#container').html(output);
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("[id*=btnsubmit]").click(function() {
                /*debugger;*/
                var obj = {};
                obj = $.trim($("[id*=tripinfo]").val());
                objs = $.trim($("[id*=tripstatus]").val());
                console.log(obj)
                console.log(objs)
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "API URL" + obj + '/' + objs,
                    //dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        //console.log(data)
                        var output = '';
                        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var driverHtml = '<div class="col-md-4 driver"><div><label class="header"><b>Driver Details</b></label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="dname">' + data[i].employeename + '</span></div><div><label>Vehicle No:</label><span class="dname">' + data[i].vehicleno + '</span></div><div><label>Mobile:</label><span class="dname">' + data[i].mobilenumber + '</span></div></div>';
                            console.log(driverHtml);

                            var passengerHtml = '<div class="col-md-8 passenger"><div><label class="header"><b>Passenger Details</b></label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="pname">' + data[i].passenger_data[0].employeename + '</span></div><div><label>Mobile No:</label><span class="pname">' + data[i].passenger_data[0].mobilenumber + '</span></div><div><label>Email:</label><span class="pname">' + data[i].passenger_data[0].email + '</span></div></div><hr>';
                            output += driverHtml + passengerHtml;
                        }
                        $('#container').html(output);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
```

Comment: It won't create HTML means, are you getting only last result? Can you please explain us more!!!

Comment: I want to create HTML as per screenshot, i get API response but it wont create HTML, i wrote loop for the same, it wont iterate through loop

Comment: Try with `data.driver_data[i].property_name...` in the loop. You should access the inner data with `driver_data`

Comment: @Sultan you said to create new question for the same

Comment: @Jon What is the difference between previous and this ?

Comment: @Sultan I Asked that why dint it create HTML, but i dint get any response i tried but i dint able to find the solution on it

Comment: @Jon If you already posted a question you should modify it to clearify it more. SO doesn't recommend to create new one.

Comment: @Jon are you checking the browser console for errors? If so what is the error you are currently getting with your attempt? **Also** CodeThing is correct. You should update your previous question rather than posting a duplicate question (with minor changes)

Comment: It dint shows any error, but it wont iterate trough loop

Comment: @CodeThing ok, will take care from next time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create dynamic html & display json values in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419044/create-dynamic-html-display-json-values-in-it)

Comment: @Zakaria any clue on this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the length of the passengers then chose the right `colclass` like :

```
$.each(data.driver_data, function(key, val) {
  var pdetails = val.passenger_data;

  output += '<div class="row">';

  output += '<div class="col-md-4 driver"><div><label class="header"><b>Driver Details</b></label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="dname">' + val.employeename + '</span></div><div><label>Vehicle No:</label><span class="dname">' + val.vehicleno + '</span></div><div><label>Mobile:</label><span class="dname">' + val.mobilenumber + '</span></div></div>';

  var colclass = '8';
  var pdetails_length = pdetails.length;

  if (pdetails_length === 1)
    colclass = '12';
  else if (pdetails_length === 2)
    colclass = '6';
  else if (pdetails_length === 3)
    colclass = '4';
  else if (pdetails_length === 4)
    colclass = '3';

  output += '<div class="col-md-8 passenger"><div class="row">';

  $.each(pdetails, function(pkey, pval) {
    output += '<div class="col-md-' + colclass + '"><div><label class="header"><b>Passenger Details</b></label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="pname">' + pval.employeename + '</span></div><div><label>Mobile No:</label><span class="pname">' + pval.mobilenumber + '</span></div><div><label>Email:</label><span class="pname">' + pval.email + '</span></div></div>';
  });

  output += '</div></div></div><hr>';
});
```

Comment: Check this @Jon

Comment: it won't apply class according to counts, it always apply col-md-8

Comment: That isn't true @Jon, have you checked the code? The fiddle console is small that why you saw it like this, but if you inspect the code you will see the right classes affected.

Comment: Check the codePen version https://codepen.io/acharki-zakaria/pen/vVGdRb

Comment: This is an old one, why not use the last version in my answer or https://codepen.io/acharki-zakaria/pen/EdKRob

Comment: This is an update of your provided fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jcq8h7b2/98/ you must replace `pdetails.count` by `pdetails_length`.

Comment: Glad I could help brother. HAPPY CODING

Comment: Note that the latest version is in the codepen https://codepen.io/acharki-zakaria/pen/EdKRob ,it will add one `Passenger Details` title for all

Comment: How Can we use paging to this,  because the results are too lengthy, & page having very large scroll down.

Comment: There are many solutions out there you may want to take a look to infinite scroll / bootstrap pagination ...give it a try and if you struggle you could post a new question

Answer (score 0):

You should access the `driver_data` and then do looping. Below is the working result and below one is the main change

```
var data = data.driver_data;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var testdata = {
    "driver_data": [{
        "tripId": 885,
        "creationDate": "2018-09-18",
        "accDestLocation": "CASA RIO Club House, Oceania Internal Road, Nilje Gaon, Maharashtra, India",
        "accDestGeoLat": "19.1481581",
        "accDestGeoLong": "73.07762149999996",
        "accEndTime": 1537277407813,
        "accScrLocation": "RCP GATE A OFFICE, Reliance Corporate Park, MIDC Industrial Area, Ghansoli, Navi Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
        "accSrcGeoLat": "19.1268537",
        "accSrcGeoLong": "73.00511699999993",
        "accStartTime": 1537277407813,
        "tripStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "createdBy": "SYSTEM",
        "bookedSeats": 0,
        "employeeid": "P10062044",
        "employeename": "Venkat Chepuri",
        "vehicleno": "MH09CQ7778",
        "vehiclecolor": "silver",
        "vehicletype": "OWN CAR",
        "vehiclemake": "hondacity",
        "srclocation": "RCP GATE A OFFICE, Reliance Corporate Park, MIDC Industrial Area, Ghansoli, Navi Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
        "srclat": "19.1268537",
        "srclong": "73.00511699999993",
        "starttime": "2018-09-18T13:30:07.813Z",
        "destlocation": "CASA RIO Club House, Oceania Internal Road, Nilje Gaon, Maharashtra, India",
        "destlat": "19.1481581",
        "destlong": "73.07762149999996",
        "seatcount": 1,
        "mobilenumber": "+917977589953",
        "email": "Venkat.Chepuri@ril.com",
        "routeid": 0,
        "distance": 14.3,
        "passenger_data": [{
          "tripId": 1015,
          "creationDate": "2018-09-18",
          "tripStatus": "CANCELLED",
          "createdBy": "SYSTEM",
          "endTime": "2018-09-18T13:21:24.882Z",
          "employeeid": "P10060725",
          "employeename": "Siva Juturi",
          "seatcount": 1,
          "starttime": "2018-09-18T13:30:36.394Z",
          "mobilenumber": "+917977526935",
          "email": "Siva.Juturi@ril.com",
          "srclocation": "RCP GATE A OFFICE, Reliance Corporate Park, MIDC Industrial Area, Ghansoli, Navi Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
          "srclat": "19.1268537",
          "srclong": "73.00511699999993",
          "destlocation": "CASA RIO Club House, Oceania Internal Road, Nilje Gaon, Maharashtra, India",
          "destlat": "19.1481581",
          "destlong": "73.07762149999996",
          "amount": null
        }]
      },
      {
        "tripId": 879,
        "creationDate": "2018-09-16",
        "accDestLocation": "Vashi, Navi Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
        "accDestGeoLat": "19.0770644",
        "accDestGeoLong": "72.99899249999999",
        "accEndTime": 1536154216056,
        "accScrLocation": "RCP GATE A OFFICE, Reliance Corporate Park, MIDC Industrial Area, Ghansoli, Navi Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
        "accSrcGeoLat": "19.1268537",
        "accSrcGeoLong": "73.00511699999993",
        "accStartTime": 1536154216056,
        "tripStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "createdBy": "SYSTEM",
        "bookedSeats": 1,
        "employeeid": "P10061231",
        "employeename": "Goutham Mekala",
        "vehicleno": "MH43W8007",
        "vehiclecolor": "DARK GREY",
        "vehicletype": "OWN CAR",
        "vehiclemake": "Hyundai i20",
        "srclocation": "RCP GATE A OFFICE, Reliance Corporate Park, MIDC Industrial Area, Ghansoli, Navi Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
        "srclat": "19.1268537",
        "srclong": "73.00511699999993",
        "starttime": "2018-09-05T13:30:16.056Z",
        "destlocation": "Vashi, Navi Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
        "destlat": "19.0770644",
        "destlong": "72.99899249999999",
        "seatcount": 1,
        "mobilenumber": "+917977589677",
        "email": "Goutham.Mekala@ril.com",
        "routeid": 0,
        "distance": 7.2,
        "passenger_data": [{
          "tripId": 995,
          "creationDate": "2018-09-05",
          "tripStatus": "CANCELLED",
          "createdBy": "SYSTEM",
          "endTime": "2018-09-05T13:22:34.065Z",
          "employeeid": "P10062044",
          "employeename": "Venkat Chepuri",
          "seatcount": 1,
          "starttime": "2018-09-05T13:30:14.197Z",
          "mobilenumber": "+917977589953",
          "email": "Venkat.Chepuri@ril.com",
          "srclocation": "RCP GATE A OFFICE, Reliance Corporate Park, MIDC Industrial Area, Ghansoli, Navi Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
          "srclat": "19.1268537",
          "srclong": "73.00511699999993",
          "destlocation": "Vashi, Navi Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
          "destlat": "19.0770644",
          "destlong": "72.99899249999999",
          "amount": null
        }]
      }
    ]
  }

  function createhtml(data) {
    //console.log(data)
    var data = data.driver_data;
    var output = '';
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var driverHtml = '<div class="col-md-4 driver"><div><label class="header"><b>Driver Details</b></label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="dname">' + data[i].employeename + '</span></div><div><label>Vehicle No:</label><span class="dname">' + data[i].vehicleno + '</span></div><div><label>Mobile:</label><span class="dname">' + data[i].mobilenumber + '</span></div></div>';
      //console.log(driverHtml);

      var passengerHtml = '<div class="col-md-8 passenger"><div><label class="header"><b>Passenger Details</b></label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="pname">' + data[i].passenger_data[0].employeename + '</span></div><div><label>Mobile No:</label><span class="pname">' + data[i].passenger_data[0].mobilenumber + '</span></div><div><label>Email:</label><span class="pname">' + data[i].passenger_data[0].email + '</span></div></div><hr>';
      output += driverHtml + passengerHtml;
    }
    $('#container').html(output);
  }

  createhtml(testdata);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Updated code**

After seeing your posted image, in the success callback function you should do like below. The change in the success callback is given by below

```
var data = data.responseJSON.driver_data;
```

```js
success: function(data) {
  var data = data.responseJSON.driver_data;
  //console.log(data)
  var output = '';
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var driverHtml = '<div class="col-md-4 driver"><div><label class="header"><b>Driver Details</b></label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="dname">' + data[i].employeename + '</span></div><div><label>Vehicle No:</label><span class="dname">' + data[i].vehicleno + '</span></div><div><label>Mobile:</label><span class="dname">' + data[i].mobilenumber + '</span></div></div>';
    console.log(driverHtml);

    var passengerHtml = '<div class="col-md-8 passenger"><div><label class="header"><b>Passenger Details</b></label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="pname">' + data[i].passenger_data[0].employeename + '</span></div><div><label>Mobile No:</label><span class="pname">' + data[i].passenger_data[0].mobilenumber + '</span></div><div><label>Email:</label><span class="pname">' + data[i].passenger_data[0].email + '</span></div></div><hr>';
    output += driverHtml + passengerHtml;
  }
  $('#container').html(output);
}
```

Comment: Good answer but similar answer like this have been posted in the OP's previous question so you might not have this marked as the solution. You might get the same response as all the others who have answered this question. *"I dint undersatand"*

Comment: @Jon  Did you check the snippet I posted? still you are getting `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. I didn't get you!!! Do one thing, in the success callback function, do console.log(data) and show us the screenshot of that

Comment: @Javascript Lover , Yes i gone through you solution i applied it but it shows error, i update my question with image

Comment: @Jon Updated the answer check now

Comment: @Jon any progress? or still getting issues?

Comment: NO now it showing
"Cannot read property 'driver_data' of undefined"

Comment: @Jon Change to `var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText).driver_data`

Comment: Also show us `console.log(data.responseText)` in the success callback using screenshot

Comment: @ Javascript Lover
Pls check my code https://github.com/vishaalmandge/FD/blob/master/Dynamic-HTML.html

Comment: @Jon what happened? still not working? can you please show us the image for `console.log(data.responseText)` in the success function

Comment: @Javascript Lover Pls chek above link, you'll get my codebase

Comment: @Jon I got the issue you are facing, I had a look at your code. but please do `console.log(data.responseText)` and show me the image

Comment: @ Javascript Lover  Check the image https://github.com/vishaalmandge/FD/blob/master/Error.PNG
What is the issue in my code, pls provide solution

Comment: @Jon I do hope the **driver_data** example isn't a copy of some true/active data.... If it is then I would recommend you replace the big list of email addresses you have just publicly displayed. Data protection...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your ajax success handler

```
var output = '';
  if (typeof data == "undefined"){
    output = 'No data available';
 } else {
    $.each(data.driver_data, function(key, val) {
    var pdetails = val.passenger_data;
    output += '<div class="row">';

      output += '<div class="col-md-4 driver"><div><label class="header"><b>Driver Details</b></label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="dname">' + val.employeename + '</span></div><div><label>Vehicle No:</label><span class="dname">' + val.vehicleno + '</span></div><div><label>Mobile:</label><span class="dname">' + val.mobilenumber + '</span></div></div>';

        var colclass = '8';
        if(pdetails.count == 1)  colclass = '8';
        if(pdetails.count == 2)  colclass = '4';
        if(pdetails.count == 3)  colclass = '2';
        $.each(pdetails, function(pkey, pval) {
                    output += '<div class="col-md-'+colclass+' passenger"><div><label class="header"><b>Passenger Details</b></label></div><div><label>Name:</label><span class="pname">' + pval.employeename + '</span></div><div><label>Mobile No:</label><span class="pname">' + pval.mobilenumber + '</span></div><div><label>Email:</label><span class="pname">' + pval.email + '</span></div></div>';
        });

     output += '</div><hr>';
    });
}
    $('#container').html(output);
```

Here is working fiddle for that http://jsfiddle.net/codething/jcq8h7b2/36/

Comment: Its working,
But how i check if there is no data in json response and display message"No data available"

Comment: @Jon Check updated code. and i just want to suggest you that you should try to execute the problem by yourself first then if you have any problem in that then only you can consult with SO here.

Comment: @Jon you can use `if (typeof data == "undefined"){` instead of this `if (!$.trim(data)){` Check my fiddle, if you rename the variable data to something else you would get this error

Comment: @Jon You have not added the change in the fiddle which i mentioned in the comment above. How it will work???
Did you tried to find why it did not worked when you empty your dataset?

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codething/jcq8h7b2/62/

Comment: its works fine, but it creates col-md-8 to each records. It should create like this<div class="col-md-8"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"></div><div class="col-md-6"></div></div></div> If 2 recods: col-md-6 3 records: col-md-4 1 record: col-md-12 Check this:http://jsfiddle.net/jcq8h7b2/68

Comment: Hi @Jon could you please describe the needs in the last comment more clearly?

Comment: @Zakaria, Pls check code in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jcq8h7b2/68 & expected as in image which attached in question.
I want html structure like this: <div class="row"> <div class="cold-md-4"> Driver details </div> <div class="col-md-8"> <div class="row"> /*If 2 passanger then it should col-md-6, if 3 then col-md-4 & if 1 then col-md-12*/ <div class="col-md-6"> Passanger details </div> <div class="col-md-6"> Passanger details </div> </div> </div> </div>