# Add class to parent menu when sub menu clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add class to the parent menu when I clicked on the submenu.

When I click on submenu then class `active` should be added to its parent, I tried but not able to achieve this, Here is my code, pls let me know what I missed in this.

**[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6y27da13/2/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-sub-link").on("click", function(e) {
    debugger;
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.sidebar-nav-link').addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/7u0pfanx/5/)**.

You could use the jQuery method `closest()` with the `$(this)` to target the clicked element parent, like :

```
$(this).closest('.sidebar-nav-item').find('a.sidebar-nav-link').addClass("active");
```

**Working sample:**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".nav-sub-link").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.sidebar-nav-item').find('a.sidebar-nav-link').addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slim-sidebar">
  <label class="sidebar-label">Navigation</label>

  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item with-sub">
      <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-link"><i class="icon ion-ios-home-outline"></i> Dashboard</a>
      <ul class="nav sidebar-nav-sub">
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link active">Page 01</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 02</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 03</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 04</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 05</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item with-sub">
      <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-link"><i class="icon ion-ios-home-outline"></i> Menu</a>
      <ul class="nav sidebar-nav-sub">
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link active">Menu 01</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 02</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 03</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 04</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 05</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why here downvote seems like he wants to remove active on click of other link. ?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted the OP says _should be added to its parent_ and the post here does this !!

Comment: @zakaria Dashboard is parent of page 01, page 02..., if i click on page 01 or page 02 etc... Active class should added to Dashboard (this class: sidebar-nav-link)

Comment: @Jon check this https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/7u0pfanx/13/ ( 3rd level sub menus should have a class `nav-sub-link` too)

Comment: @Zakaria could you pls help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437673/can-not-create-dynamic-html-using-ajax-call

Comment: I saw it yesterday, but when I saw one of the answers was marked I thought that you've found the solution.

Comment: @fcalderan could you please tell us why you've downvoted the correct answer here?

Comment: @zakaria when i clcik on submenu it redirects to other page & on that page i want parant menu with active class
Eg:
Pages is parent menu & page , page2 submenus. i click on page1 it redirects to other page, on that page i want Pages should be active

Comment: In this case, you need to use `cookies` or `localStorage`

Comment: @Zakaria could you pls help me in this? How i use cookies or localStorage for this

Comment: Hi Jon, Try to add a new question with the detailed info about this case and let me take a look to it.

Comment: @Zakaria Ok, pls check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699679/how-to-use-cookies-or-local-storage-for-add-a-class-to-parent-of-sub-menu

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `parents()` Jquery method to find it's parents when clicked the elements.

```js
$(function() {

  $(".nav-sub-link").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $('.sidebar-nav-item .sidebar-nav-link').removeClass("active");
    $(this).parents('.sidebar-nav-item').find('.sidebar-nav-link').addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slim-sidebar">
  <label class="sidebar-label">Navigation</label>

  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item with-sub">
      <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-link"><i class="icon ion-ios-home-outline"></i> Dashboard</a>
      <ul class="nav sidebar-nav-sub">
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link active">Page 01</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 02</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 03</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 04</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 05</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item with-sub">
      <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-link"><i class="icon ion-ios-home-outline"></i> Menu</a>
      <ul class="nav sidebar-nav-sub">
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link active">Menu 01</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 02</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 03</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 04</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 05</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: its working, but could you pls check for 3rd level sub menus as well, check this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7u0pfanx/9/