# How to use cookies or local-storage for add a class to parent of sub-menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, local-storage

I have 2 different pages with common sidebar menu. In my example, you can see Parent Menus with Submenus. In Dashboard I've page1 sub-menu, when I click on it, redirects to other pages, I want in sidebar Parent menu should add a class. Even I refresh the page.

Here is my HTML code

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3znovkbg/2/)

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item with-sub">
        <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-link"><i class="icon ion-ios-home-outline"></i> Dashboard</a>
        <ul class="nav sidebar-nav-sub">
            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="menu1.html" class="nav-sub-link">Page 01</a></li>
            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 02</a></li>
            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 03</a></li>
            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 04</a></li>
            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 05</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item with-sub">
        <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-link"><i class="icon ion-ios-home-outline"></i> Menu</a>
        <ul class="nav sidebar-nav-sub">
            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 01</a></li>
            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 02</a></li>
            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 03</a></li>
            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 04</a></li>
            <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 05</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item with-sub">
        <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-link"><i class="icon ion-ios-book-outline"></i> Pages</a>
        <ul class="nav sidebar-nav-sub">

            <li class="nav-sub-item sub-with-sub">
                <a href="#" class="nav-sub-link">Pricing</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="sub-sub-link"><a href="">Pricing 01</a></li>
                    <li class="sub-sub-link"><a href="">Pricing 02</a></li>
                    <li class="sub-sub-link"><a href="">Pricing 03</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, you could use the jquery lib `js-cookie` to add the selected menu to the cookies then read it in the other pages and attach the class.

But I suggest another way based on the URL of the page target the related anchor them activate the parent sidebar menu item.

Add the following line to the top of your ready function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href="'+window.location.pathname+'"]').closest('.sidebar-nav-item').find('.sidebar-nav-link').addClass('active');

    ...
});
```

Comment: It will not work in the fiddle since the fiddle don't do the real redirect so `window.location.pathname` will be always a random string, have you tried it locally or in your server?

Comment: yes i did.
These are my pages https://github.com/vishaalmandge/FD/blob/master/menu.html & https://github.com/vishaalmandge/FD/blob/master/menuother.html

Comment: Add an `alert(window.location.pathname)` before or after the line and let me know what is the content

Comment: it shows page name (menuother.html) on menuother page & (menu.html) on menu page same page

Comment: Its not working, It redirects to other page but it dint add active class to parent

Comment: have you tried the statements here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181477/discussion-between-jon-and-zakaria-acharki

Comment: Do you have always the same problem Jon ?

Comment: pls help me for sort it out

Comment: The problem is that it works in my side, I'll check with you using the chat room

Comment: I'm trying this code but not working, i think i've missed something in it
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#sidebar-menu a").each(function () {
         var pageUrl = window.location.href.split(/[?#]/)[0];
         if (this.href == pageUrl) {
             $(this).addClass("active");
             $(this).parent().addClass("active"); 
             $(this).parent().parent().prev().addClass("active");
 });
Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3znovkbg/8/

Comment: I'm trying this, but it wont work: $(".slim-sidebar ul li.with_sub a.active").parents("li:last").children("a:first").addClass("active").trigger("click");